# .net Soap Service with out class mapping to be consumed by PHP

Tags: php, .net, soap

Just building a new site, we will be building a .net soap service to supply the data to a php site.

I used a fair amount of .net soap services in php, some of which you need to map classes and some that you just provide an array of php data to the service.

Our .net developer has only ever built soap services with class mapping, I would prefer it if we just had to supply a simple array of data to the service. As it will mean making changes will be a lot simpler.

What needs to be enabled on the .net side to allow this, and what are the benefits / pit falls of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

PHP as the Soap client will best work if a WSDL ressource is provided, but apart from that, no further classes are needed - you can use any construct of arrays and/or stdClass objects for the parameters.

But it will make life a lot easier if you use the classmap feature of the SoapClient, e.g. your IDE would complete the names of properties for you, and when debugging you know which part of the object you are dealing with. But it is entirely optional.

The server part has nothing to do with it. But be aware that using the more fancy stuff in SOAP might make it a lot harder for PHP to be the client. If you want this to be easy going, I'd stay away from more complicated structures like XML attributes.

In a response, `<element>value</element>` will be fine, `<element attrib="value"/>` might not. But don't take my word for it, I'm just using Java Soap services a lot in PHP, and we don't have attributes.